# how to associate a buffer with existing python-shell in emacs

Tags: emacs

if I want to associate the buffer with a SQL shell, seems I can do sql-set-sqli-buffer.
if I want to associate the buffer with a python shell, what command should apply ?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIU question is around a linked output buffer

WRT python-mode.el

http://launchpad.net/python-mode

you may consider a feature-request, giving some more details concerning 
expected workflow